# IIS rewrite rule with has tag

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

In my site , I have to write IIS redirect rule with has tag e.g.

Source URL   `www.abc.com/resources/#forpatients` should redirect to  `www.abc.com/care-team-corner/resources`

and below rule I wrote but its not working :-

```
 <rule name="withhash">
<match url="resources/#forpatients$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*\.?www.abc\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="www.abc.com/care-team-corner/resources" redirectType="Permanent" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
  </rule>
```

I search on google and found that "The URL fragment (everything from # on) not even gets sent to the server."  So what would be alternative approach  ?    Should I use Jquery and compare the URL and then redirect

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to do this on IIS side

Since web browser will never send #string to server side, URL rewrite won't able to receive it.

Even if you send request via other client like fiddler. HTTP.SYS will intercept the request and return 400 -URL invalid.

[image]
[image]

If you want to redirect URL based on specific string segment with URL rewrite, you should include it into URI or query string.

Otherwise, you have to do redirection on client side.